# Get Average of TimeSpans with EF Core

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I'm using EF Core 7 with Postgres. I need to calculate some stats:

```cs
public record Job(string Name, DateTime Started, DateTime Stopped);
public record Stats(TimeSpan Min, TimeSpan Mean, TimeSpan Max);

// 

var stats = await _context
  .Jobs
  .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
  .Select(x => new Stats(
    x.Min(y => y.Stopped - y.Started), 
    new TimeSpan((long)x.Select(y => y.Stopped - y.Started).Select(x => x.Ticks).Average()), 
    x.Max(y => y.Stopped - y.Started)
  ))
  .ToListAsync();
```

The average subquery is weird-looking but works as a non-EF query. But EF refuses with:

> InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'RelationalGroupByShaperExpression:
> ...
> .Average()' **could not be translated**. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation

I think EF can't translate `Ticks`. I didn't find anything useful in `EF.Functions`.

I don't want to do this on the client, I want to do this on the database as the data set is large. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than client-side eval, one could use a provider-specific function (I am using Postgres):

```cs
var stats = await _context
  .Jobs
  .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
  .Select(x => new Stats(
    x.Min(y => y.Stopped - y.Started), 
    EF.Functions.Average(x.Select(y => y.Stopped - y.Started)),  // <---
    x.Max(y => y.Stopped - y.Started)
  ))
  .ToListAsync();
```

But then that property must be nullable:

```cs
public record Stats(TimeSpan Min, TimeSpan? Mean, TimeSpan Max);
```

The issue is `Ticks` is not (currently) supported. That was [requested here](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/27103), please upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, entity framework does not understand the concept of TimeSpan.Ticks.

However, class [DbFunctions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbfunctions?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) has several methods to get the number of (nano)seconds / minutes / hours, etc between two DateTimes. Select the accuracy that you need, for example:

```
var stats = await _context
    .Jobs
    .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .Select(x=> new
        {
            Min = x.Select(y => y.Stopped - y.Started).Min(),
            AverageTimeSpanMilliSect = x.Select(y =>
                    DbFunctions.DiffMilliSeconds(y.Stopped, y.Started)
                .Average(),
            Max = x.Select(y => y.Stopped - y.Started).Max(),
        })

    // Move the selected data to your local process and convert to Stats
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => new Stats(x.Min, 
                           TimeSpan.FromMilliSeconds(x.AverageTimeSpanMilliSec,
                           x.Max));
```

Comment: Thanks. I looked for something like that in `EF.Functions` but found nothing. I'm using Postgres and my `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.dll` does not contain that method. I suspect that's for EF Framework, not EF Core. Maybe this cannot be done in the db, but only on the client? That would be surprising though.

Comment: Consider to add an extension method that executes your code in SQL. Or investigate  the source code of `method DbFunctions.DiffMilliseconds` and rewrite it in your language